# Array assignment Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to do the following assignments in Javascript:

```
data.field[0].myArray = array[0];
data.field[1].myArray = array[1];
data.field[2].myArray = array[2];
...
```

Of course I could use a loop:

```
for (i= 0; i< array.length; i++) {
    data.field[i].myArray = array[i];
}
```

But I wonder if there is any other way to do it in a cleaner way.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: whats wrong with iteration?

Comment: Nothing wrong, I only wanted to know if there is a more "elegant" way to do this

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do it without iterating, doesn't make sense of having such way either!

Comment: Of course iteration is necessary, the author just wants cleaner code.

Comment: @simon author want to know if there is a way of doing it without iteration! There is no mention of any cleaner code

Comment: It's only a few lines as it is. The most important thing is readability and who doesn't know how to read a basic for loop?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar my fault, I wanted to know if there is a cleaner way. I have edited my post.

Comment: @Genzotto trust me it can't get any cleaner than that.. or oh wait.. this one liner for (i= 0; i< array.length; i++) {data.field[i].myArray = array[i];} still want it cleaner? Jokes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but that's still iterating the array:

```
array.map(function(item, index){
    data.field[index].myArray = item
});
```

However, you may want to <sub>(should)</sub> make sure `data.field[i]` actually exists:

```
array.map(function(item, index){
    data.field[index] = data.field[index] || {};
    data.field[index].myArray = item
});
```

Please note that, `array.map()` [doesn't work in IE 8 or lower](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility). You can **[use a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill)**, if you need to support lower versions of IE.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: That's what I said.

Comment: So, @Genzotto, does this answer your question?